# how to show/hide login and logout after user authentication in node-express app

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, javassist

How can i show or hide login/logout link if user is loged in.
my code works for for logged in user but is never show register and login links.

this is what i have tried so far this:
javascript:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
    });
```

ejs code:

```
     <%if (typeof user !== 'undefined') { %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/user/register">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/user/login">Sign in</a>
        </li>
     <% } else {%>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="/logout">Sign Out</a>
        </li>
     <%}%>
```

Comment: You should use session or cookie

Comment: like how can you be more specific

Comment: Stephen Grider docker course on udemy has illustrated Elastic Beanstalk with docker in details.